# Kubernetes | Monitor HPA's Current and Target CPU Utilization using Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to monitor the current/target CPU utilization at the deployment/HPA level using Prometheus. GCP Kubernetes monitoring has these metrics available on Stackdriver dashboard but could not find them how they are tracking it.

Following links contains the list of HPA metrics exposed, which does not have the required/target CPU utilization.
https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/1dfe6681e9/docs/horizontalpodautoscaler-metrics.md

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a look at [cAdvisor](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-usage-monitoring/#cadvisor). Actually, cAdvisor is a part of [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) service and represents itself as a monitoring agent for performance and resource usage by the containers within particular node. By default, cAdvisor exposes container statistics across Prometheus [metrics](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/storage/prometheus.md#prometheus-metrics) which are available in `/metrics` endpoint for each container. I guess you can use `container_cpu_load_average_10s` metric in order to fetch CPU utilization per each container for relevant Pod/Deployment.